# i am searching for default.properties file for missing proguard.cfg

Tags: android

i am new to android,
when i create a project with 1.5 to 2.1, i gives me the same error that proguard is missing from there path.
according to recently asked questions here, i am searching for defualt.properties file,,,, but it is not present,, where i can find this, please give me full solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

default.properties file is present in the root of your project.if you don't find it just search in sample applications comes with  android sdk. and copy it from there to your projects root.

may be this will help you.

Comment: @Aamir..welcome..But please vote up or except the ans from which you satisfied. so that more people will help you in near future.